# PHP Question about bitwise

Tags: php, bitwise-operators

I have a script like this

```
$job = array(
        1 => 'User',
        2 => 'Editor',
        4 => 'Supervisor',
        8 => 'Manager',
        10 => 'President');

$value = 18;

foreach($job as $key => $val)
{
   if($value & $key)
   {
      $job[] = $key;
      echo $val.', ';
   }
}
```

now what I want to achieve is that in the example above '18' system must only display the value as ' Manager, President, ' ( 10+8 = 18; )

But if you run the script, the system displays as Editor, President,

that's not all the arrays I've got, I have like 23 more array values

Sorry but I really can't explain it in english, hope you understand...

Comment: Your values should be in powers of 2 if this is what you're going for, so you can use bit flags (normal addition won't work). Try using 1,2,4,8,16, etc. instead.

Comment: Terrible idea... Not easily maintainable by future programmers. And it requires too much thought. It should be explicit coding, not implicit.

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php

  $flags = array(
    1   => 'User',       // 00000001 Note the place of the 1
    2   => 'Editor',     // 00000010
    4   => 'Supervisor', // 00000100
    8   => 'Manager',    // 00001000
    16  => 'President'   // 00010000
  );

  // permission we're going for
  $permissions = 16 + 8; // 00011000  again, note the 1's places.

  $levels = array();
  foreach ($flags as $level => $name)
  {
    if (($permissions & $level) == $level)
      $levels[] = $name;
  }
  echo implode(', ', $levels);
```

**Output:**

```
Manager, President
```

You want your values in powers of 2 so that, in binary, the corresponding flag matches the permission you're specifying.

The bit-wise AND (`&`) is saying (when it reaches **Manager**):

```
    $flags     $Pemissions   $flags
if (00001000 & 00011000) ==  00001000
if       (00001000)      ==  00001000 [true]
```

Basically, if the flag is set on both sides (both the value you're checking for and against) keep that bit. Then, make sure it still equals the value you're checking for. If it does, the user is set to that permission. An AND is only true when **both** the left **and** the right values have the bit(s) set.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, I know that I must follow that array of bits... but I just want to experiment something so I decided to ask for some help hehe... thank you once again... much explained for me +1 for this... sorry I can't vote up right now :D

Answer (score 1):

The value for President is wrong. To use a bitfield all numbers must be powers of two, so President should be 16 and not 10.

Note that 16 (decimal) is 0x10 (hex) -- perhaps setting the President value to 10 (decimal) was a copy/paste error?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that 10 is not a 2^y variable.

10 = 2+8 (2^1 and 2^3), and thus will match values 2 and 8 respectively.

If you want to allow bitwise selection like you do; you *need* to pick 2^y values for your indexes (1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, etc).

Then you can safely add those values as selectors (e.g. 16+4 (20), 2+32(34) etc).

Comment: Are there any resolution to my query? so that I can use that kind of array?

Answer (score 0):

you should change 10 to 16 (1,2,4,8,16,32, ..) or you may cannot understand some number. Is 10=10 or 10=2+8